# Туториал Хартла ROR 5.0.0 проблема с майлером

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Прохожу туториал https://www.railstutorial.org/book  by Michael Hartl завис пока на 11 главе с майлером. как я полагаю хрен знает каким макаром action не может вытащить данные User.first непонятно из-за чего.. помогите плиз
если нужны подробности - говорите.  Т_Т

[image: ошибка]

app/mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
    class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def account_activation(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
  end

  def password_reset
    @greeting = "Hi"

    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end


end
```

app/mailers/user_mailer_preview.rb

```
# Preview all emails at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer
class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview

  # Preview this email at
  # http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer/account_activation
  def account_activation
    user = User.first
    user.activation_token = User.new_token
    UserMailer.account_activation(user)
  end

  # Preview this email at
  # http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer/password_reset
  def password_reset
    UserMailer.password_reset
  end
end
```

я прохожу туториал на Cloud9 IDE так что прописал в config/development.rb URL

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800'
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  host = 'rails-tutorial-jude-ostorn.c9users.io' # Don't use this literally; use your local dev host instead
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host, protocol: 'https' }

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
  config.assets.quiet = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
end
```

Comment: ну всё-же ruby наверое можно было оставить. но вам виднее.

Answer (score 1):

окей. я решил не париться ни за что.  и просто доделать до конца..  получается как я до сих пор не могу открыть эти preview однако как костыль вот вам вариант. просто используйте что-то вроде

```
  def account_activation
    @greeting = "Hi"

    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
```

однако например на heroku с использованием sendgrid всё работает отлично. сообщения отправляются, и проблем не возникает. т.е подтверждение пароля через почту - работает.

если вы найдёте решение проблемы пожалуйста поделитесь .